How to focus first dropdown item after opening dropdown menu (w/ NVDA screen reader)?
I'm working on a dropdown menu for a navbar and when focused on the dropdown menu button, I want it so that if the "Enter/Return" or "Space" keys are clicked the dropdown menu opens and establishes focus on the first item.
I have a TS method that handles this behavior, but if I test it with NVDA running it opens the dropdown menu but ignores this logic and maintains focus on the dropdown menu button.
This is the routine that I have currently:
  const onToggleKeyDown = (evt: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    const targetEl = evt.currentTarget;
    const title = targetEl.getAttribute("data-title");

    if (evt.code === "Tab") {
      return;
    }

    if (evt.code === "Enter" || evt.code === "Space") {
      evt.preventDefault();

      if (title === openDropdown) {
        setOpenDropdown(null);
      } else {
        setOpenDropdown(title);
        const popups = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
        for (let i = 0; i < popups.length; i++) {
          if ((popups[i] as HTMLDivElement).getAttribute("data-popup") === `${title}`) {
            (popups[i].firstChild as HTMLLIElement).focus();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (evt.code === "Escape") {
      setOpenDropdown(null);
    }
  };

Does anybody know of a workaround for this or what might be causing it? I've tried wrapping the for-loop portion in a window.setTimeout (thinking it was a timing issue) but that doesn't solve the issue.
